# Java: Make sure the last 9 digits in ArrayList unique

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

trying to make a Sudoku game, but stuck at checking (and fixing) duplicates in rows and columns

```
        if (buttons.getSource().equals(newGame)) {
        String diffic = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose difficulty, ranging from 1-3 where 1 is easy");
        int difficulty = Integer.parseInt(diffic);
        ArrayList<Integer> allnumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));

        if (difficulty == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {

                fields.get(i).setEditable(true);
                fields.get(i).setText("");
                double d = Math.random();
                if (d < 0.6) {
                    random = new Random();
                    Integer randomInt = allnumbers.get(random.nextInt(allnumbers.size()));
                    fields.get(i).setText(randomInt + "");
                    fields.get(i).setEditable(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

As of now, it prints and stuff works, but it prints duplicated numbers.
My pseudo-way right now: 
1. Find a way to print the arraylist in random order for each row. The random part is done, but it still prints duplicated numbers (im thinking to print numbers 1-9 in random order 9 times, 1 time for each row)
2. Find a way to check columns afterwards. No clue how yet, taking one problem at a time

Anyone here been around the same problems, got some tips?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an `ArrayList` with the nine number.
2. Use `Collections.shuffle(...)` to shuffle the numbers in random order.